# How to fix an error when installing a PhantomJS bridge for node.js on Windows 7 64-bit?

Tags: node.js, phantomjs

I am getting following error when I try to install `phantom` in my windows 8 64bit.

```
$ npm install phantom
```

```
E:\pay\node_modules\phantom\node_modules\dnode\node_modules\weak>node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: spawn ENOENT
gyp ERR! stack     at errnoException (child_process.js:1001:11)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:792:34)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
gyp ERR! command "node" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd E:\l7pay\node_modules\phantom\node_modules\dnode\node_modules\weak
gyp ERR! node -v v0.10.33
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v1.0.1
gyp ERR! not ok
npm WARN optional dep failed, continuing weak@0.3.3
phantom@0.7.0 node_modules\phantom
├── win-spawn@2.0.0
├── traverse@0.6.6
├── dnode@1.2.0 (jsonify@0.0.0, dnode-protocol@0.2.2)
└── shoe@0.0.15 (sockjs@0.3.7)
```

Comment: You probably want to organize your post a little bit. How to format code block: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Comment: Have you tried turning it off and on again? No, really. Sometimes node has problems with a fresh install.

Comment: yes I tried but still the same error showing

Comment: @ArtjomB. I really doubt an npm install will help, since there is a file missing.

Comment: my requirement is to generate a PDF using phantom. Do you have any alternate solution or sample code? thanks